# Retrieve items matching tags, and simultaneously retrieve all tags that go along with each item

Tags: mysql, join, tags, where-in

I have the following tables, relevant to this question:

```
project
- projectId (PK)
- projectTitle
- projectDescription
- etc..

tag
- tagId
- tagName
- tagDescription
- etc...

project_tag
- projectId (PK / FK -> project.projectId)
- tagId (PK / FK -> tag.tagId)
```

I'm implementing tag functionality similar to what StackOverflow has, in that one is able to view a list of items (projects, in my case) tagged by one or multiple tags.
What I'm trying to do is select all projects that, at a minimum, are tagged with all tags that I feed to the query, but simultaneously retrieve all tags that go with each individual project.

What I have now works, but I have the feeling that the subquery in the `WHERE IN` clause is very inefficient, as this would probably be executed for each row, correct?

```
SELECT
    `project`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `tagName` ORDER BY `tagName` SEPARATOR ' ' ) as `tags`
FROM
    `project`
JOIN
    `project_tag`
    USING ( `projectId` )
JOIN
    `tag`
    USING ( `tagId` )
WHERE
    `projectId` IN (
        SELECT
            `projectId`
        FROM
            `project_tag`
        JOIN
            `tag`
            USING ( `tagId` )
        WHERE
            `tagName` IN ( 'the', 'tags' )
        GROUP BY
            `projectId`
        HAVING
            COUNT( DISTINCT `tagName` ) = 2 # the amount of tags in the IN clause
    )
GROUP BY
    `projectId`
```

Is there any way to JOIN on `tag` such that I am able to simultaneously retrieve *all* tags for the `JOIN`ed project, while only `JOIN`ing projects that (at a minimum) match all tags I feed to the query, without having to use the `WHERE IN` clause?

To illustrate an example result, consider these example projects:

```
projectId: 1, tags: php, cms, webdevelopment
projectId: 2, tags: php, cms, ajax
projectId: 3, tags: c#, cms, webdevelopment
```

Searching for the tags `php` and `cms` would yield (these are not formatted as the actual mysql query result, it's just to illustrate the relevant data):

```
projectId: 1, tags: php, cms, webdevelopment
projectId: 2, tags: php, cms, ajax
```

Not just:

```
projectId: 1, tags: php, cms
projectId: 2, tags: php, cms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub query is non correlated (it can be taken out and executed on its own without errors) so should be executed once.

Might be more efficient to have a subquery to exclude the non matching projects first, and join back the other tables against that. Something like this:-

```
SELECT project.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tagName ORDER BY tagName SEPARATOR ' ' ) as tags
FROM (SELECT projectId, COUNT( DISTINCT tagName ) AS TagCount
        FROM tag
        INNER JOIN project_tag USING (tagId)
        WHERE tagName IN ( 'the', 'tags' )
        GROUP BY projectId
        HAVING TagCount = 2) Sub1
INNER JOIN project ON Sub1.projectId = project.projectId
INNER JOIN project_tag USING (projectId)
INNER JOIN tag USING (tagId)
GROUP BY projectId
```

I assume you have an index on tagName.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. `The sub query is non correlated...`; ah yes, that makes sense. Just before you answered I actually came up with a similar query as the one you suggest. But I actually didn't have an index on `tagName`, so I've added that now. The column is a `VARCHAR(50)` (for now, still in development stage). Would you recommend I set an index length as well?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about setting a length on that index. For testing remember that if the number of tags in the IN clause is large compared to the number of possible tags that MySQL will likely ignore the index (roughly around 10%, which is very easy to hit when using limited test data).